# Why does production of electron come with either electron neutrino or positron?

Tags: particle-physics, conservation-laws, pair-production

I read that when an electron is produced, it always comes either with an electron neutrino or with a positron. Why is that so?
Why doesn't an electron come instead with say a muon neutrino or antimuon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no deeper theory from which the existence of three lepton flavors follow. Also no one knows the origin of lepton flavor conservation, which reflects the fact that creation of an electron requires simultaneous creation of a positron or an electron *anti* neutrino. [Lepton flavor is approximately conserved law.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lepton_number#Violations_of_the_lepton_number_conservation_laws)